# Are there receivers and transmitters that can be tuned to multiple frequencies at once?

Tags: receiver, frequency, transmitter

What kind of hardware/circuitry would be needed for a device to be able to transmit and receive over a range of frequencies at once?

Comment: This question is really to vague. This could mean independent multi-band, multi-standard operation just as much as it could refer to a single  multicarrier transmission. Can you please list an example of what you mean?

Comment: A **repeater** listens on one frequency and transmits on another; ham radio transceivers know how to talk to it. But it doesn't sound like that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A software-defined radio (SDR) with appropriate programming can transmit and receive multiple signals inside a given band.